# How to check if there is an index on a column through Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I do `Image.column_names` and that shows all the columns such as `post_id` but how do I check if `post_id` has an index on it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is an [index_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_exists%3F) method on one of the ActiveRecord "connection adapters" classes.

You can use it like on of the following methods:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.connection.index_exists? :images, :post_id
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_exists? :images, :post_id
```

If you know the name of the index, instead you'll need to use `index_name_exists?`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_name_exists? :images, :index_images_on_join_key
```

Comment: It always returns `false` even in case for `:id` attribute. Am I doing anything wrong `Referral.connection.index_exists? :referrals, :id` ?

Comment: @kamal `index_exists?` checks that any index exists on the column. Do not know how it is checked, but for me it also sometimes returns false. There is also [index_name_exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-index_name_exists-3F) to check index by name, it works well for custom indexes

Comment: @ololobus but this method `index_name_exist?` requires to know by index name, which is hard to know because you don't even know whether there is index or not or for which you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 29):

As others have mentioned, you can use the following to check if an index on the column exists:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_exists?(:table_name, :column_name)
```

It's worth noting, however, that this only returns true if an index exists that indexes that column and only that column. It won't return true if you're using compound indices that include your column. You can see all of the indexes for a table with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:table_name)
```

If you look at the source code for `index_exists?`, you'll see that internally it's using `indexes` to figure out whether or not your index exists. So if, like me, their logic doesn't fit your use case, you can loop through these indexes and see if one of them will work. In my case, the logic was thus:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:table_name).select { |i| i.columns.first == column_name.to_s}.any?
```

It's also important to note, `indexes` does not return the index that rails automatically generates for ids, which explains why some people above were having problems with calls to `index_exists?(:table_name, :id)`

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_exists?(:table_name, :column_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

For an updated answer, as of Rails 3+ multi-column, uniqueness and custom name are all supported within the `#index_exists?` method.

```
# Check an index exists
index_exists?(:suppliers, :company_id)

# Check an index on multiple columns exists
index_exists?(:suppliers, [:company_id, :company_type])

# Check a unique index exists
index_exists?(:suppliers, :company_id, unique: true)

# Check an index with a custom name exists
index_exists?(:suppliers, :company_id, name: "idx_company_id")
```

Source: [Rails 6 Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_exists%3F)

Comment: I just found that while `unique: true` only returns true for unique indexes, `unique: false` does NOT test that the index is non-unique. `index_exists?` will return true for an otherwise matching unique index even when requesting `unique: false`.